# How do I swap arrays in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Ugh. I had passed an array that is part of a larger structure to have elements removed from it using the `-=` operator. Unfortunately, it looks like this is only syntactic sugar for `a = a - b` and thus generates a new object, which the larger structure won't see. Yes, I know that I can probably make it so that the new object could be returned and then be assigned to the larger structure, but I'd rather not. Is there a method that modifies the original object?

## Additional

In most languages, the default `-=` operator refers to modifying the original object, and it kills me that Ruby decided to go a different way.  Does anyone know the reason for this?

Comment: I guess I could do `c = a - b; a.clear.concat c` but it still irks me a little.

Comment: @muistooshort, That would have a O(n^2), which would be crappy.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of a, b and the expected output? If you have `a = [1, 2, 3]` and `b = [2, 3, 4]` are you expecting a to equal `[1]` without a new object being returned?

Comment: If you have the array `a = [1, 2, 3]` and call `a *= ","` then `a` will be the string `"1,2,3"` afterwards. Apparently it can’t be the same object (array vs. string).

Comment: @DaniG2k, yes.  No change in behaviour other than the original object is modified/returned.

Comment: Hmmm. Seems to be a limitation of the language as you cannot overload `-=`.  `a -= b` is just an alias for `a = a - b`, which is crappy and confusing.  Ruby should have at least a `swap` method which can be overload so that it can create a proper `-=` implementation, even if they don't want to allow the dev to implement a `-=` directly.

Comment: [Array#replace](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Array.html#method-i-replace) maybe?

Comment: @Adrian you can use `Array#delete`.  O is not n^2 but only n. It is absolutely the same as `Array#-`

Comment: @AlexeySchepin there's a subtle difference though: `delete` compares via `==` (more loosely) and `-` compares via `eql?` (more strict), i.e. `[1,2,3].delete(2.0)` does remove `2` from the receiver whereas `[1,2,3] - [2.0]` returns `[1,2,3]`.

Comment: @AlexeySchepin, so are you saying that `Array#delete` is O(1)? Otherwise, how could an equivalent `[a1,...,an] - [b1,...,bn]` using `Array#delete` be anything other than O(n^2)?

Comment: @maxpleaner, `Array#replace` looks better, and `c = a - b; a.replace  c` is at least more inline with the intent. Might even be implemented  such that it only copies the data pointer to the array data with CoW semantics. I'd be willing to accept this as an answer.

Comment: @Adrian, no. It's O(n), not a constant. You need O(log n) to find an element + O(n) to delete it. So it's O(n) in total. 
If you want to delete an array of size m it's O(n*m). You can check source code for `Array#-` https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-2D it had the same performance

Comment: @AlexeySchepin, yeah, O(n*m) is what I actually meant.

Comment: `In most languages, the default -= operator refers to modifying the original object` - you mean in the languages where arrays are implicitly passed by reference instead of value, right? As an `-=` operator requires the array pointer to be passed by reference (lvar, inout, etc)